# select deselect checkbox

Tags: javascript-remoting

i had created checkbox on visualforce in contact table. i used javascript to make it function able. select all ceckbox is functioning properly but when i deselect any row check box then select all box also not deselect can anyone plzz help me where m wrng

```
<apex:page controller="CopyOpportunityList" >
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID)
       {
        try{
                var tableCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                var rowCount=tableCheckBox.length;
                for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
                {          
                    if(tableCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1)
                    {                                     
                        tableCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                    }
                }
           }
           catch(e)
           {
            alert(e);
           }
       }
     function deSelect(obj)
    {    
        var selectAllBox =jQuery('#selectallChk');
        if(obj.checked==false)
        {
            selectAllBox.checked=false;
            //document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:selectedConList:ConList:selectallChk").checked=false;
        }
    }

    </script>

<apex:pageBlock title="Contact List" id="selectedConList">            
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="ConList" value="{!myContactList}" var="c" rendered="{!(myContactList.size > 0)}">

                    <apex:column >
                       <apex:facet name="header">
                          <apex:inputCheckbox  onclick="javascript:selectAllCheckboxes(this);" id="selectallChk" />
                       </apex:facet>
                       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.CheckBoxValue}" id="inputId" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="https://ap5.lightning.force.com/{!c.accContact.Id}" target="_blank">{!c.accContact.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                     <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="https://ap5.lightning.force.com/{!c.accContact.AccountId}" target="_blank">{!selectedAcc}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
```

Comment: You haven't added half code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of work I recommend using CSS classes as markers (i.e. the classes have no associated CSS) as Id values get prefixed and get dow indexes added:

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:inputCheckbox  
                onclick="javascript:selectAllCheckboxes(this);"
                id="selectallChk"
                styleClass="allCheckbox"
                />
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:inputCheckbox
            value="{!c.CheckBoxValue}"
            id="inputId"
            styleClass="rowCheckbox"
            />
</apex:column>
```

so in your JavaScript you can e.g. differentiate between the "row" ones and the "all" one:

```
var allCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName("allCheckbox")[0];
var rowCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("rowCheckbox");
```